# A raw dump from a corrupted large file

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, ntfs, file-corruption

I have a large `.rar` file inside partion `D` (Windows7/NTFS). It's corrupted due to bad sector (I think) and when I copy it to another place (External-HDD) the system freezes after 88% of progress. I even tried to copy it with my Ubuntu and same problem occurred.
Also I tried `chkdsk` and it dosen't fix it.

I think my last chance is dump that file with a tool which ignores bad sectors and create a raw copy of it. Then I will repair the file with `rar` tools.

But I can not found a tool to raw dump a specific file. (In linux there is `dd` tool but it dumps all partition and I can not use it)

So, Is somebody know a tool to do a raw dump from a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dd` to copy any file to anywhere (i.e. it's not limited to partitions). You can even ignore any read errors by using `conv=noerror`.

However, the "freezes" you observe are the disk retrying to read the bad sector and causes the read command to block. This will still happen with `dd`, but it will manage to continue after a timeout.

Comment: Really?! How `dd` can use for a single file? Do you have an example?

Comment: Just put a file name after the `if` or `of` parameter. The second line of the man page even says `dd - convert and copy a file `.

Comment: `conv=noerror,sync` would be better, since it will pad the missing parts with NULs. Even better would be using something like `ddrescue` (in the package `gddrescue` in Debian/Ubuntu, not `dd_rescue`) to clone the whole drive/partition and mount it for reading later. `ddrescue` is designed for recovery from damaged drives and will recover as much as possible by skipping damaged sections on the first pass.

Answer (score 1):

There is a russian software nscopy.
It copies the file skipping BAD blocks. You may skip them with settings retry bad blocks reading=1 and number of passes to copy bad blocks=1 or you may try to copy them setting passes=0 for infinite :)
I used it many times to rescue data from scratched CDs, DVDs, from HDDs with BADs.
It's free! Try it!